# Convert jsonparser code from json.org library to Gson library

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am new to Gson library and I am struggling to find an appropriate way to parse a very simple json data using Gson. Heres the sample json.

```
{
"response": {
    "status_code": "200",
    "message": "User successfully registered.",
    "response_for": "register"
}
}
```

I parse it like follows using json.org library bundled with android.

```
try {
        JSONObject root = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONObject response = root.getJSONObject("response");
        int status = response.getInt("status_code");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

As for Gson the problem I am having is creating POJO classes. I am only intrested in the status_code value of the response so creating a pojo class is a waste. The sample Gson I tried is as follows:

```
JsonObject root = new Gson().fromJson(json, JsonObject.class);
Sring result = jobj.get("test").toString();
```

With this code I am only able to parse non-nested json.

Comment: use JsonArray Object to parse nested json http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/

Comment: @KamleshArya but there is no jsonarray in my sample json so do I have to do it??

Comment: Your link is using org.json classes and not gson classes I need to change my parsing code to gson

Comment: the structure of `JsonObject.class` is depends on the type of response you are getting. if response contains nested object you should have to create class with child object. for more details see [this](http://www.javacreed.com/gson-deserialiser-example/)

Comment: @maddy I know that andI am trying to avoid it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am only intrested in the status_code value of the response so
>   creating a pojo class is a waste.

Then why do you need to use Gson in the first place.

Quoting gson docs "It can be used to convert a JSON string to an equivalent Java object"

To just get the `status_code` your first method should work.

Using Gson

```
public class Response { 

Res response;
}
```

Then have

```
public class Res {

public String status_code;
public String message;
public String response_for;

public Res(){}
}
```

Then

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader (is);
Gson gson = new Gson();
Response lis = new Gson().fromJson(isr, Response.class);
Log.i("Response is  ",""+lis.response.status_code);
Log.i("Message is ",""+lis.response.message);
Log.i("Response_for is ",""+lis.response.response_for);
```

The Log

```
06-13 17:55:52.126: I/Response is(8776): 200
06-13 17:55:52.126: I/Message is(8776): User successfully registered.
06-13 17:55:52.126: I/Response_for is(8776): register
```

Comment: I will use POJO classes for Gson for other complex json object. This is the sample to know that the authentication was successful and my project needs a whole lot of json parsing. Do I have to make pojo classes for such simple json then I might use my first method for such cases. But I am not sure just started using Gson.

Comment: @IllegalArgument use the first method. But if you want java objects then use gson.

Comment: it works but i was looking for a solution without using pojo classes and using json. I need to parse a whole lot of json than this and my class count is already 100+ lol. I guess I will use two json parser gson and json.org this was my worst case scenario.

Comment: @IllegalArgument for your case since you need only status code. the 1st method is OK. But you have to decide whether you want java objects or not. It does not matter whether you need to parse a small amount or more

Comment: @IllegalArgument how many activities do you have? If you have more then 30 or 50 then there is something wrong with your design

Comment: I have about 8 activies like register,login and others. I have a whole lot of fragments about 75 fragments including stuffs like no internet dialog. A whole lot of pojo classes json parsing and data validation almost 45% of the code. Its basically like fb app heres the website http://rugbyworlddirectory.com/

Answer (score -1):

following code returning the string value.

```
 "status_code": "200",
"message": "User successfully registered.",
"response_for": "register"
```

and you are getting it with integer, i think you have to write like this,

```
 JSONObject root = new JSONObject(json);
 JSONObject response = root.getJSONObject("response");
 int status = Integer.parseInt(response.getString("status_code"));
```

please try this, may be it will work.

Comment: This is the code I posted in the question itself. Please read carefully.

Comment: please read properly my code, i have edited this line : int status = Integer.parseInt(response.getString("status_code"));

Comment: in the code first i m getting value from responce in string and the converting that string in integer

Comment: I know and it is a wasted code. What is the point of converting 200 which can be directly fetched as an integer to string and back to Integer again??

Comment: if you get that value with integer will give the parsing error.